# clearTimeout on multiple references

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of complex setTimeout() calls that trigger some jQuery animations.
I would like to be able to clear them all without knowing their various refs.

This code will not work - but should illustrate what I'm trying to do...

```
window.ref = [];
function doAnimation(i) {
    $('div').each(function(index) {
        window.ref.push(setTimeout('foo(index,i)',index*1000));
        window.ref.push(setTimeout('bar(index,i)',index*2000));
    });
}
```

Then clear them with

```
clearTimeout(window.ref);
```

Comment: Perhaps create an object within which you can register these setTimeouts, and a function of that object that can clear them, store them, or do whatever it needs with them. A doAnimation setTimeout 'manager'.

Comment: Instead of setting up multiple timeouts, you could just set up two and let them work on a queue.

Comment: @FelixKling: Or use a single interval to animate the frames on that queue.

Comment: FYI, this method will accumulate old (already fired) timer IDs in the `window.ref` array that don't even need to be cleared (because they've already fired).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (window.ref && window.ref.length > 0) for (var i in window.ref) {
   clearTimeout(window.ref[i]);
}
```

Or do it the jQuery way:

```
$.each(window.ref, function (index, value) { clearTimeout(value); });
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this already has an accepted answer, but just because those timeout ids are worthless once you have cleared them, I would have cleared them by saying:

```
if (window.ref) while(window.ref.length > 0) clearTimeout(window.ref.pop());
```

Comment: +1 for elegance. However I couldn't resist making a small improvement.

Comment: I'm always down for improvements. I thought about doing something similar. like `if (!!window.ref && window.ref.constructor == Array)`, since the original question was explicitly saying `window.ref = [];` I thought null and type checking wasn't really required. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 2):

thats not correct you should do like this:

```
window.ref = [];
function doAnimation(i) {
    $('div').each(function(index) {
        window.ref.push(setTimeout('foo(index,i)',index*1000));
        window.ref.push(setTimeout('bar(index,i)',index*2000));
    });
}
```

and then clear like :

```
for(var i=0;i<window.ref.length;i++){    
    clearTimeout(window.ref[i]);
}
```